# Can I reload stylesheets in JavaFX 8 without a JVM restart?

Tags: java, clojure, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using Java 1.8u25 and I am using a stylesheet as below (both Java and Clojure equivalents).

```
//Java
new Pane().getStylesheets().add("some_style.css")

//Clojure
(doto (Pane.)
  (-> .getStylesheets (.add "some_style.css")))
```

I'm using Clojure, and I don't restart the JVM between test runs. I do, however, make a new GUI, of new instances, for each run. JavaFX caches the stylesheet somewhere, so editing the CSS file has no effect. Is there a way to force JavaFX to reload the stylesheet? Or, a way to reload classes so that the cache is lost?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are not *setting* or *changing* the stylesheet but *adding* a stylesheet:

```
new Pane().getStylesheets().add("some_style.css")
```

You call the `add()` method! So basically it's your `Pane` that caches the previously loaded stylesheet.

Solution is simple: before loading it again, remove (clear) the old one:

```
Pane p = new Pane();
// Load first time:
p.getStylesheets().add("some_style.css");

// Later to reload:
p.getStylesheets().clear();
p.getStylesheets().add("some_style.css");
    // some_style.css will be read again and applied
```

**Note:**

If you use multiple CSS files, `clear()` might not be what you want here. In this case instead of `clear()` you can remove a specific style sheet (which you want to reload) with the `remove()` method before adding it again.

**Note #2:**

When loading CSS files, you should use URLs to resources, not just a file name. If only file name is provided, it must contain the package name too. Do it like this which works both from file system and from a jar file:

```
p.getStylesheets().add(YourClass.class.getResource("some_style.css")
    .toExternalForm()); // if some_style.css is next to YourClass.java
```

Comment: Should maybe have been clearer: It's not the same instance between runs. I make a new Pane instance. Also, I tried to add, clear, then add again on the same instance, which you said should work, but it does not. I'm pretty sure there is a cache, as discussed [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2296345?tstart=0). But the method `reloadStylesheets` mentioned there seems to be gone.

In the worst case, I'll just temporarily rename the css file to trick the cache.

Comment: @oskarkv I checked it with the same `Pane` instance. Adding the style sheet, then changing the CSS file then clearing the stylesheets and adding again worked for me.

Comment: Which version of Java do you use? Also I tried changing the name of the CSS file, then it worked (one time) as expected.

Comment: @oskarkv I tested it with 1.8.0_20.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually do exactly what you did. I edited the CSS file, *then* added, cleared, added, just to check if the clear-call would remove it from some cache. What you did is not actually what I want to do, because I want to edit the CSS then run my program from start to finish, but without restarting the JVM in between runs. Anyway, I have implemented an acceptable renaming scheme for now. Of course, it would be great if someone knew of a better solution.

Comment: @oskarkv I did what I did without restarting the JVM: I started the JFX app, which loaded the CSS file. Then edited the CSS (while the app is running), then I clicked on a button which reloaded the (now modified) CSS file, and the changes I made in the CSS file were visible in the app without JVM restart.

Comment: Came across this question searching for answers.  It seems like modifying a CSS file 'on the fly' and having it used while outdated can cause an error.  It must get reloaded before the scene has to re-draw anything.  A button reload works, but a context menu can't be shown without throwing an error.

Comment: As of fx2.1 stylesheets are not cached. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8100613

Answer (score 0):

My development method is the same: JavaFX using Clojure in a repl, editing css, not restarting JVM.

I have found the following 2 "rules" apply:

1. Don't add your stylesheet to a Scene.  It won't update (clear) even if you attempt all the tricks in the book.  Strangely, it does change after a certain amount of time after all Stages are closed. Can't figure out why, though.
   Instead, add it to a Parent node.
2. Make sure all Stages are closed.  Your old styles won't update if any Stages are open. Something to do with caching and threads I think.

UPDATE:
The above is not great as CSS won't be applied to pop-ups and dialogs.
After further testing, I found that I (maybe because of the way I build my JavaFX objects in Clojure I needed to "re-apply" my CSS to the scene after a certain delay.

I now have the following code fragments which seem to work well for me.
(I can even ignore "rule 2".)

```clj
(defn fxthread? []
  (Platform/isFxApplicationThread))

(defn later* [expr]
    (if (fxthread?)
      (try (expr) (catch Throwable e e (println e)))
      (Platform/runLater #(try (expr) (catch Throwable e e (println e))))))

(defmacro future-sleep-later [ms & body]
   `(future (Thread/sleep ~ms) (later* (fn [] ~@body))))

(defn external [path]
  (.toExternalForm (cio/resource (str path))))

(defn add-stylesheet [scene-or-parent path & [refresh? delay]]
  (let [css (external path)
        ss  (.getStylesheets scene-or-parent)]
    (.add ss css)
    (when refresh?
      (future-sleep-later (or delay 2000)
        (doto ss (.remove css) (.add css))))
    scene-or-parent))
```